# increment column value command in hbase via pig

Tags: hbase, increment, apache-pig

Is there a way I can increment a column value in an hbase table with pig?
I'm trying to write in pig something that will increment a value of a column in an hbase table that is equivalent to this hbase shell command:

```
hbase> incr ‘t1′, ‘r1′, ‘c1′
```

Is is possible to do this with pig?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a macro for this purpose:

```
DEFINE incr(A, fld, num) RETURNS B {
    $B = foreach A generate k, ($fld + (long)$num) as (v:long);
}

A = load 'hbase://t1' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
 'f1:c1', '-caster=HBaseBinaryConverter -loadKey=true') as (k:chararray, v:long);

B = incr(A,v,3); --increment f1:c1 by 3

store B into 'hbase://t1' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
 'f1:c1', '-caster=HBaseBinaryConverter -loadKey=true');
```